# Undersampling of a non periodic pulse signal

Tags: sampling, trigger

I am starting getting familiar with electronics, consider me as a newbie.. I am facing a sampling trouble with my DAQ system. I have a non periodical pulsed signal with a separation between the pulse that varies from 3 to 6 ms. The pulses' width is 100us. I want to be able to trigger my DAQ in such a way that it acquires data whenever a new pulse appears. I know exactly the number of trigger counts I am expecting. My electrometer is able to integrate from 55us to 1000us. However, even using the shortest integration periods (55us and 100us and minimum conversions per sample) I am missing (undersampling) pulses. I would appreciate some ideas about how to get the optimal sampling rate or how to test my electronics to find th solution. I am running out of them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have said that it has the range for frequency and then you speak about the pulse width? how did you calculate the pulse width? I think it's incorrect!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, by "range" I meant the bandwidth of my signal, i.e the separation between the pulses varies from 1 to 3 ms.

Comment: What DAQ system are you using?

Comment: A multichannel electrometer connected to my experimental setup.

Comment: You are confusing terms. "Bandwidth" is not the "separation between the pulses". If you have 100 us pulses, then you have a bandwidth that's at least 5 kHz -- possibly much higher, depending on the shape of the pulses. Your sample period needs to be less than 100 us in order get even a single sample of the pulse, and this won't necessarily be aligned with the peak. Smaller sample periods will work better.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Dave. I understand that my sample period has to be shorter than my pulse width. However even with my shortest integration period (55us) I am undersampling, missing about 28 trigger counts.

Comment: Are you actually measuring the pulse or just using the pulse as a trigger to know when to measure something else? If so is important that the something else be time-refernced to the pulse particularly accurately?

Answer (score 1):

If you can "trigger" from the pulse through a digital IO pin (say via a comparator) then you can "capture" the amplitude via a sample and hold circuit. As soon as you detect a pulse, sample the signal and then put the sample and hold circuit into "hold" mode. You can then measure the amplitude via the ADC in a more leisurely fashion.

I'm suggesting this because you appear to know the pulse width but you are "missing" some pulses because of undersampling.

If in fact you are interested in knowing the shape of the top of the pulse by taking several ADC readings during the pulses duration then this technique won't help.